# How to hide the listitems in master page based on user login in asp .net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

Below are my listitems in master page which are fileupload and reports now i have a login page,fileupload and reports page as content pages my requirement is before the user gets logged in i need to hide both file upload and reports and once the user logins based on his role i need to hide the list items that is if the designation of user is manager i should show both file upload and reports and if the designation is user i need to show only file upload.So based on the user role at the time of login i need to do this.how can i do this
code in master page

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <%-- <li class="navigation_first_item"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>--%>
    <li><a href="FileUpload.aspx">File Upload</a></li>
    <li><a href="Reports.aspx" id="Rpf" runat="server">Reports</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code behind in master.cs, create method to check user has access rights for specific menu/page. e.g :

```
public bool HasRightsForSpecifiedMenu(string menuItemName)
{
  string userLoggedIn=((Session["UserLoggedId"]!=null)?Session["UserLoggedId"].ToString():"0");
  string userType=((Session["UserType"]!=null)?Session["UserType"].ToString():"0");
  if(menuItemName=="fileupload"){
    if(userLoggedIn=="0" || userType!="Manager")
      return false;
  }
  else if(menuItemName=="report"){
    if(userLoggedIn=="0" || !(userType=="NoramlUser" || userType=="Manager"))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Now in your inline (masterpage/menupage.aspx) write stuff to allow html to render menu items :

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<% 
    If(HasRightsForSpecifiedMenu("fileupload")==true){ %>
    <li id="MenuFileUpload" runat="server"><a href="FileUpload.aspx">File Upload</a></li>
    <% } %>

    <% 
    If(HasRightsForSpecifiedMenu("report")==true){ %>
    <li id="MenuReports" runat="server"><a href="Reports.aspx" id="Rpf" runat="server">Reports</a></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
</div>
```

You can maintain `UserLoggedIn` and `UserType` status in session variable in login success code.

Comment: i am not unable to pass those ids in code behind that is respective .cs pages where should i place your above code in content pages or masterpage

Comment: i had tried in that way but its not working moreover based on the user role after login i need to hide one tab that is if he is an user i should hide reports page and if he is a manager i need to show both file upload and reports page and before login i need to hide both file upload and reports how can i do this

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, check it. let me know if need more clarify it.

Comment: Thank you for your response but i need to hide both file upload and reports tab before login and and after login i need to hide reports based on the roles here i am getting the data in datatable and i that datatable 4th column is the designation which has two designations as manager and user so if(dt.rows.count>0) means i will be entering into if condition the how should i catch the fourth column values and hide the tabs can you please help me out as i am new to this please dont update the ans post this seperately

Comment: 1. You may have maintain logged in user status in session variable, so replace your session variable name here : Session["UserLogedIn"]

2. To get designation from datatable : string des_=dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();

Comment: but login takes place at one of the content page and we are restricting the tabs in the code behind of master page then how this can be acheived

Comment: In login method you have to maintain session variable which will be accessible in your entire application.
We can call public methods from code behind to content page.

Comment: Can you show me your login method code so i can explain you more.

Comment: protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        DataTable dt = adm.GetUsers(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("FileUpload.aspx");
           
        }
        else
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "Invalid username or password";
        }
    } this is my code in login page

Comment: ok, i think you just want to show menu by user type, do this change in your login method first :
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
Session["UserLoggedId"] = "1"; // to maintain login status for application
Session["UserType"] = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString(); // set user type to for further menu hide logic
Response.Redirect("FileUpload.aspx"); 
}

Comment: I have updated my answer for solution, please check it.
And don't forget to do ( +1 to answer, Mark correct answer, +1 to my comments )

Comment: i am gettin this error Error 20 Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'near !(userType="NoramlUser" || userType="Manager")

Comment: Ohh,.. use it like : (userType=="NoramlUser" || userType=="Manager"),
i've updated answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                   <%-- <li class="navigation_first_item"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>--%>
                    <li id="MenuFileUpload" runat="server"><a href="FileUpload.aspx">File Upload</a></li>
                     <li id="MenuReports" runat="server"><a href="Reports.aspx" id="Rpf" runat="server">Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```

in master page `.cs` file u could call at PageLoad function like:

```
MenuFileUpload.Visible = false;
MenuReports.Visible = false;
```

Hope this help !

Comment: i am not unable to pass those ids in code behind that is respective .cs pages where should i place your above code in content pages or masterpage

Comment: at your masterpage.cs

Comment: i had tried in that way but its not working moreover based on the user role after login i need to hide one tab that is if he is an user i should hide reports page and if he is a manager i need to show both file upload and reports page and before login i need to hide both file upload and reports how can i do this

Comment: could u post ur code completely 2 file. masterpage.aspx and masterpage.cs, we take a look at it !